# hp dl380 g4 hardware monitor software

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

I've just bought a used hp proliance DL380 G4.
This kind of servers are new to me...

I've got it up and running WHS2011 without any problems.

It has 2 power supplies , 2 processors and raid.
I would like a notification (preferable by email or sms) if one of the components fail.
Now if i unplug a power supply or hdd..it keeps on running..but i can't see it anywhere
(except bios bootup)

What software would i need.
Tried to install hp inside manager..but that did not install..and seems way to big.

Thanks

Comment: Better off asking this on serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great piece of hardware.
You need to install HP Proliant Support Pack (free download from HP).
It can send traps and emails (but email functionality is a little less than perfect).
You can also use HP SIM (Systems Insight Manager) but it's probably an overkill for just one system.  Also free from HP.

Comment: THANKS...  did not see that at first on software page..works perfect.